# How to configure email for Bugzilla on windows 8.1 x64 and XAMPP?

Tags: email, xampp, windows-8.1, bugzilla

I have an issue with sending a mail from my bugzilla installation. 
Specifications:

- Local installation (`http://localhost/bugzilla`)
- Windows 8.1 pro x64
- XAMPP Server
- bugzilla 4.4.4 installed using **bzr** in `c:\xampp\htdocs\bugzilla`
- ActivePerl 1604 x64

A `perl checksetup.pl` output:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\Bugzilla>perl checksetup.pl
* This is Bugzilla 4.4.4 on perl 5.16.3
* Running on Win8 Build 9200

Checking perl modules...
Checking for               CGI.pm (v3.51)     ok: found v3.64
Checking for           Digest-SHA (any)       ok: found v5.85
Checking for             TimeDate (v2.23)     ok: found v2.24
Checking for             DateTime (v0.28)     ok: found v1.10
Checking for    DateTime-TimeZone (v0.79)     ok: found v1.71
Checking for                  DBI (v1.614)    ok: found v1.63
Checking for     Template-Toolkit (v2.22)     ok: found v2.25
Checking for           Email-Send (v2.16)     ok: found v2.199
Checking for           Email-MIME (v1.904)    ok: found v1.926
Checking for                  URI (v1.37)     ok: found v1.60
Checking for       List-MoreUtils (v0.32)     ok: found v0.33
Checking for    Math-Random-ISAAC (v1.0.1)    ok: found v1.004
Checking for                Win32 (v0.35)     ok: found v0.48
Checking for            Win32-API (v0.55)     ok: found v0.75

Checking available perl DBD modules...
Checking for               DBD-Pg (v2.7.0)    ok: found v2.19.3
Checking for            DBD-mysql (v4.001)    ok: found v4.022
Checking for           DBD-SQLite (v1.29)     ok: found v1.40
Checking for           DBD-Oracle (v1.19)     ok: found v1.68

The following Perl modules are optional:
Checking for                   GD (v1.20)     ok: found v2.50
defined(@array) is deprecated at C:/Perl64/site/lib/Chart/Base.pm line 181.
        (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)
defined(@array) is deprecated at C:/Perl64/site/lib/Chart/Base.pm line 233.
        (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)
Checking for                Chart (v2.1.0)    ok: found v2.4.6
Checking for          Template-GD (any)       not found
Checking for           GDTextUtil (any)       ok: found v0.86
Checking for              GDGraph (any)       ok: found v1.48
Checking for           MIME-tools (v5.406)    ok: found v5.505
Checking for          libwww-perl (any)       ok: found v6.05
Checking for             XML-Twig (any)       ok: found v3.44
Checking for          PatchReader (v0.9.6)    ok: found v0.9.6
Checking for            perl-ldap (any)       ok: found v0.64
Checking for          Authen-SASL (any)       ok: found v2.16
Checking for         Net-SMTP-SSL (v1.01)     ok: found v1.01
Checking for           RadiusPerl (any)       ok: found v0.22
Checking for            SOAP-Lite (v0.712)    ok: found v1.11
Checking for          XMLRPC-Lite (v0.712)    ok: found v0.717
Checking for             JSON-RPC (any)       ok: found v1.04
Checking for              JSON-XS (v2.0)      ok: found v2.34
Checking for           Test-Taint (any)       ok: found v1.06
Checking for          HTML-Parser (v3.67)     ok: found v3.71
Checking for        HTML-Scrubber (any)       ok: found v0.09
Checking for               Encode (v2.21)     ok: found v2.56
Checking for        Encode-Detect (any)       not found
Checking for          Email-Reply (any)       ok: found v1.203
Checking for HTML-FormatText-WithLinks (v0.13)     ok: found v0.14
Checking for          TheSchwartz (v1.07)     not found
Checking for       Daemon-Generic (any)       not found
Checking for             mod_perl (v1.999022) not found
Checking for     Apache-SizeLimit (v0.96)     not found
Checking for        File-MimeInfo (any)       not found
Checking for           IO-stringy (any)       ok: found v2.110
Set up gcc environment - gcc.exe (rubenvb-4.5.4) 4.5.4
***********************************************************************
* OPTIONAL MODULES                                                    *
***********************************************************************
* Certain Perl modules are not required by Bugzilla, but by           *
* installing the latest version you gain access to additional         *
* features.                                                           *
*                                                                     *
* The optional modules you do not have installed are listed below,    *
* with the name of the feature they enable. Below that table are the  *
* commands to install each module.                                    *
***********************************************************************
*      MODULE NAME * ENABLES FEATURE(S)                               *
***********************************************************************
*      Template-GD * Graphical Reports                                *
*    Encode-Detect * Automatic charset detection for text attachments *
*      TheSchwartz * Mail Queueing                                    *
*   Daemon-Generic * Mail Queueing                                    *
*         mod_perl * mod_perl                                         *
* Apache-SizeLimit * mod_perl                                         *
*    File-MimeInfo * Sniff MIME type of attachments                   *
***********************************************************************
COMMANDS TO INSTALL OPTIONAL MODULES:

    Template-GD: ppm install Template-GD
  Encode-Detect: ppm install Encode-Detect
    TheSchwartz: ppm install TheSchwartz
 Daemon-Generic: ppm install Daemon-Generic
       mod_perl: ppm install mod_perl
Apache-SizeLimit: ppm install Apache-SizeLimit
  File-MimeInfo: ppm install File-MimeInfo

Reading ./localconfig...

OPTIONAL NOTE: If you want to be able to use the 'difference between two
patches' feature of Bugzilla (which requires the PatchReader Perl module
as well), you should install patchutils from:

    http://cyberelk.net/tim/patchutils/

Checking for            DBD-mysql (v4.001)    ok: found v4.022
Checking for                MySQL (v5.0.15)   ok: found v5.5.32

Removing existing compiled templates...
Precompiling templates...done.
checksetup.pl complete.
```

I want to configure it with our test host, so I have configured *Administration > Parameters > Email* as:

- **mail_delivery_method:** STMP
- **mailfrom:** MY_USERNAME@MY_DOMAIN.com
- **use_mailer_queue:** off
- **smtpserver:** mail.MY_DOMAIN.com
- **smtp_username:** MY_USERNAME@MY_DOMAIN.com
- **smtp_password:** MY_PASSWORD
- **smtp_ssl:** off
- **smtp_debug:** on

Also there is SECOND option of using gmail, but I went through [this](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Windows_Gmail) document, but I did not get any result. The answer might be simple, but as do not know perl at all, I might not find it.

So can you instruct me how I can get the bugzilla emails work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came out to be the installation of the `sendmail`, I assumed that it should be installed in: `c:\xampp\htdocs\usr\lib\sendmail.exe`, since my bugzilla installation was: `c:\xampp\htdocs\`, but I was wrong.
The installation of sendmail, irrespective of the installation of bugilla `c:\usr\lib\sendmail.exe`. To sum-up steps that solved my problem:

- Downloaded the latest version of the *sendmail* and changed *sendmail.ini* to appropriate values
- located sendmail and all the files that came bundled with it at: `c:\usr\lib\`
- Changed the permissions, so that *any one* can *read*, *write* and *execute* the *sendmail.exe*
- Changed the compatibility settings of the *sendmail.exe* for *all the user* to run with *windows xp PS3* and *run as administrator*

Also remember to choose *sendmail* as the send method of the bugzilla.